# How to use boolean IF the value of boolean depends on user input?

Tags: c#

I just started to learning writing code in C# and I have no idea how to use boolean if the value of it is only determined by the user input

example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eqample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Write \"yes\"");
            Console.ReadLine();


            if (Console.ReadLine() == "yes")
            {
                bool q1 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bool q1 = false;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(q1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare the `bool` outside the `if` statement.

Comment: `bool q1 = Console.ReadLine() == "yes";`

Comment: The problem as @Sean pointed out is that you declare your bool inside the if-statement, which means that the variable q1 does not exist outside the if scope or else scope.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really understand your question but I can see your code cannot run, right?
Just change it to

```cs
            Console.WriteLine("Write \"yes\"");

            bool q1 = Console.ReadLine() == "yes";

            Console.WriteLine(q1);
            Console.ReadLine();
```